# Issue installing openmp on mac using homebrew

Tags: c++, openmp, homebrew

I'm trying to use Openmp on my mac, but i'm getting a compiler error I don't understand. I installed openmp using

```
brew install llvm
```

When I try to compile my code using -fopenmp I get errors like this

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "std::runtime_error::what() const", referenced from:
  vtable for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> > in ccOEbbPM.o
  vtable for boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> in ccOEbbPM.o
  vtable for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::range_error> > in ccOEbbPM.o
  vtable for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::overflow_error> > in ccOEbbPM.o
  vtable for boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::range_error> in ccOEbbPM.o
  vtable for boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::overflow_error> in ccOEbbPM.o
  "std::locale::operator==(std::locale const&) const", referenced from:
  boost::detail::lcast_put_unsigned<std::char_traits<char>, unsigned long long, char>::convert() in ccOEbbPM.o
 "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_first_not_of(char, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0u, 0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)1, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >::do_get_string[abi:cxx11](std::_Ios_Fmtflags, mpl_::bool_<false> const&) const in ccOEbbPM.o
 "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const", referenced from:
  std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& boost::multiprecision::operator<< <boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0u, 0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)1, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >, (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)1>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0u, 0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)1, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >, (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)1> const&) in ccOEbbPM.o
```

It's just a small segment of the error code since it goes on for quite a while, but I post the rest if need be. I also have the boost library installed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

Simple program that causes the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){


int x = 5;



#pragma omp parallel
for(int y = 0; y < 50;y++){
  x += 5;
}

  cout <<  x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Commands used to compile:

```
gcc-7 -fopenmp -Wall ex.cc

gcc-7 -std=c++11 -fopenmp -Wall ex.cc (I get less errors doing it this way)
```

Error when using the second compile command:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)
(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
  _main in ccXt8Pa8.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
  _main in ccXt8Pa8.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccXt8Pa8.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccXt8Pa8.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
  _main in ccXt8Pa8.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
  _main in ccXt8Pa8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please show the simplest possible program that causes the error. Also, please show the command you use to try and compile it.

Comment: I edited the code with a program and the commands used.

Comment: Use `g++-7` and all will be fine - it is C++ after all ;-)

Comment: Wow such a simple solution but it worked lol thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem - I have put it as an answer so folks don't have to scrabble around in the comments in future to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `g++-7` rather than `gcc-7`, and all will be fine - it is C++ after all ;-)

```
g++-7 -std=c++11 -fopenmp openmp.cpp -o openmp
```